# Flutter Avatar in diamond style

Tags: flutter

Does anyone have an idea how to acheive this:

An Avatar with a diamond curve shape.  So baiscally a rounded rectangle rotate by 45% with an image that stretch to the inner boxconstraint.

[image]

Comment: Add a picture or something for better explanation

Comment: I added it in my attempt to find the better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around a bit, I found that I can use a combination of Stack and a CustomCliper implementation.  I'm not sure this is the best way, but at least it works!

".rotate(***)" is from the library styled_widget.  You can achieve the same by using the This is the same thing as wrapping the Container with Transform.rotate(***)

To achieve this:

[image]

```
 Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
              ClipPath(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              child: Container(
                height: 80*sqrt2,
                width: 80*sqrt2,
                child: Image.asset(
                  "images/Marianne-F.jpg",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              clipper:  DiamondRounded(),
            ),
            Container(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              height: 80,
              width: 80,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(width: 3, color: Colors.deepOrange[800]),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6))),
            ).rotate(angle: 45 * pi / 180),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: What is DiamondRounded?